# Create table with Geometry Column in hadoop Hive

Tags: geoprocessing, references, hadoop, hive

Is there a way to add a geometry column in hadoop? Please give me some getting-started tutorial for geoprocessing in hadoop. Like, I have a database which have point values and if I take a random point, I need to check all the values which come under 10km radius of that point.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Esri GIS Tools for Hadoop](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/)?  It includes an implementation of ST_Geometry for Hive, in the [Spatial Framework for Hadoop](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop).

You can start with the [samples](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/tree/master/samples).

There are example calls to the various ST_Geometry UDFs in the scripts under [spatial-framework-for-hadoop/hive/test/](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/tree/master/hive/test).

(Disclosure: I'm a collaborator.)  (Update: added more hyperlinks.)